# Crystal Reports in Visual Studio custom value

Tags: .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

under C#/.NET I am using Crystal Reports to print something. One of the columns is Datetime type. When it is not null, I want to print this Datetime. That works. But when it is null for some row, I want to print "Not filled in".

I guess I have to use some formula like

```
If IsNull({TABLE.FIELD}) Then "Not filled in" Else {TABLE.FIELD}
```

But I do not know where to write this formula.

Comment: you need to use formula fields and there write this formula

Answer (score 0):

Try this out might help you

If IsNull({TABLE.FIELD}) Then "Not filled in" Else ToText(date({TABLE.FIELD}))